# How to make a measurement in a subspace?

Tags: measurement

I am currently reading this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.101.032307) by Xin et al. (2020) in which they perform a measurement in a particular subspace. In the caption of Figure 6 (last sentence) they say " At the end of the circuit, we measure the state of the work system in the subspace where all ancilla registers are $|0⟩|0⟩_k |0⟩_{kL}$." What I am having trouble understanding is how they ensure that the ancilla qubits are in the state $|0\rangle$. How do I design my circuit to transform them into this state?

Comment: I haven't read the linked paper but one possibility is to simply measure everything and post-select those outcomes where the ancilla qubits were in the $\vert 0\rangle$ state.

Comment: My concern with that method is that the probability amplitudes will be different then if I were to force the ancilla qubits to $|0>$ within the circuit prior to measurement. My best guess is that I would need to take an inner product to measure in the subspace that I am interested in but I don't know how to build an inner product circuit.

Comment: It is doubtful that they mean to force the ancillas to be in state $|0\rangle$. Instead, they probabl mean "if the ancillas are in state |0\rangle$, measure the worksystem, i.e. a controlled-measurement.